# use matched argument from IN() function

Tags: mysql

im using the **IN()** function to match againts some ids.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN(id1,id2,id3)
```

the thing is, now i need to calculate a **SUM()** based on the matched id, and i would like to do it on the same query. Something like

```
SELECT *,(SELECT SUM() WHERE id = the_matched_id) FROM my_table WHERE id IN(id1,id2,id3)
```

¿is it possible? maybe i should consider to change my query, or do it separately. ¿ What a do you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the sum of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matched `ID` is just the `ID` of each row from the outer table. You can use different aliases to compare these `ID`s.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(summableColName) FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
FROM my_table t1 WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT id,sum(field) FROM my_table WHERE id IN(id1,id2,id3)
GROUP BY id
```